# My Hats disappeared!

Tags: bug, status-completed, winter-bash-2016

I noticed that sometimes the Winter Bash icon on the top bar next to the achievements icon disappeared along with my hats. Still not able to reproduce it 100% but I am able to trigger it few times.

1. Go to SO meta
2. Tap the Winter Bash icon
3. Tap any hat
4. Browser redirect to SO user profile page without opening the hats page
5. Hats are gone!! Refresh doesn't help. Force reload sometime fixes it.
6. Sometimes after refresh, the hats icon are back with lots errors in browser console.

---

OS: macOS 10.12.2 (16C67)

Browser: Safari Technology Preview Release 19 (Safari 10.1, WebKit 12603.1.14.2)

Can't reproduce on Chrome 56 and Safari 10.0.2. Maybe it is Safari Technology Preview's issue.

---

Sometimes the Winter Bash icon is visible but no hats

[image]

Lots errors
[image]

Sometimes different errors
[image]

Note: Google Analytics is block by my pi-hole DNS proxy. But I don't think it matters in this case.

---

Update: on rev 2016.12.19.5397 pref-tracking bug seems fixed. But still one Winter Bash bug remaining

```
[Error] TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'WinterBash.hats.getHatDivToFitInside')
    (anonymous function) (qa-wb.js:1:7983)
    each (jquery.min.js:2:2886)
    m (qa-wb.js:1:7588)
    success (qa-wb.js:1:2973)
    i (jquery.min.js:2:27455)
    fireWith (jquery.min.js:2:28215)
    y (jquery.min.js:4:22733)
    onreadystatechange (jquery.min.js:4:27970)
```

[image]

---

Update 2: Disabled AdBlock and clear cache and disabled my pi-hole.

The above issue seems fixed, but still one more...

```
[Error] WebSocket connection to 'wss://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com/' failed: WebSocket is closed due to suspension.
```

And navigate to SO hats profile form meta doesn't always bring up the hats screen. Refresh sometimes fixes it. No more errors in console. The WebSocket error sometimes show up when I navigate to meta again.

Comment: Did you wipe your cache?

Comment: Clear browser cache doesn't help.

Comment: seems to be our client-side perf tracking code (see https://teststackoverflow.com), fix incoming

Comment: are you using adblock or something similar?

Comment: Yes. I am using https://github.com/pi-hole/pi-hole and AdBlock. I can reproduce the issue with AdBlock disabled. pi-hole only blocks DNS query, which in this case, https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js

Comment: @m0sa don't know if it's of interest but there's a typo on teststackoverflow.com: 'The intent is to keep **ay** eye on performance and evaluate...'

Comment: Seems more like a feature to me than a bug

Answer (score 91):

Should be fixed in next build, (rev `2016.12.19.5397` on MSE/MSO, `2016.12.19.4354` on sites).

Comment: Only on SO 50+ upvotes to fix hats...got a huge PL/SQL issue..1 upvote...maybe.

Comment: @JonH, but your PL/SQL issue got solved as well, right? ;)

Comment: @JonH It will be fixed in 6-8 hats.

Comment: @AndrasDeak Nailed it.